# How do I encapsulate commonly used HTML blocks using node, hogan-express?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, hogan.js

I'm learning about node, express, hogan/hogan-express and using them to build out a form that looks similar to:

```
<div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" />
</div>
...more label, input combinations
```

Rather than copying and pasting like similar blocks over and over again, is there a way I can encapsulate the common HTML into a template and or partial but specify different values for each instance?

Conceptually, what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<div>
    <label {{attributes}}></label>
    <input {{attributes}} />
</div>
```

if possible into a custom tag (e.g. form-input).  Then in my markup, do something like:

```
<form-input {
   label:  {
       for: "firstName"             
   },
   input: {
        name:  "firstName"
        data-something:  "something"
   }
}/>
<form-input {
   label:  {
       for: "lastName"             
   },
   input: {
        name:  "lastName"
        data-something:  "something else"
   }} 
/>
```

Is this possible to do using hogan-express and templates/partials?  Or would I need to create my own middleware that parses custom tags and renders the corresponding HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what hogan-express is used for. I have never used Hogan, so you'll have to excuse my syntax, but this is the idea. Say you had a route:

```
app.get('/showform', function(req, res) {
 res.render('views/myform', {
   elements: [{
    name: 'firstName',
    label: 'First Name'
   },{
    name: 'lastName',
    label: 'Last Name'
   }]
})
```

Then in your template

```
//myform.html
<form>
  {{#elements}}
    <label for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
    <input name="{{name}}" type="text" />
  {{/elements}}
</form>
```

Comment: I see.  It’s starting to make sense, but what if I wanted to add different attributes to the the input fields in the template? For example,  

elements: [{
    data-x: ‘x’
   },{
    data-y: ‘y’
   }
   },{
    data-a: ‘a’
    data-b: ‘b’
    data-c: ‘c’
   }
]

From what I understand, the template would change to

<input name="{{name}}" type="text" data-x=“{{data-x}}“ data-y=“{{data-y}}“ data-a=“{{data-a}}“ data-b=“{{data-b}}“ data-c=“{{data-c}}“ />

And the resulting HTML would contain empty attribute values when the attribute value could not be found.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript templating engines, both the concept and implementation, are still new to me, but after doing some research and spending more time with hogan-express, below is what I came up with:

**Partial**

labelText.html

```
<div>
    <label for="{{for}}">{{labelText}}</label>
    <input name="{{name}}" type="text" {{#attr}}{{name}}="{{value}}"{{/attr}}/>
</div>
```

Note:  the '/' that closes the attr variable causes html validators to fail

**app.js**

Inform node/express about the partial so that it can be used on any page

```
app.set("partials", {
    labelText: "labelText"
});
```

**Useage**

```
{{#firstNameField}}
    {{> labelText }}
{{/firstNameField}}
{{#lastNameField}}
    {{> labelText }}
{{/lastNameField}}
```

**Backing data (or hash)**

```
res.render('/', {
        firstNameField: {
            for: "firstName",
            labelText: "First Name",
            name: "firstName",
            attr: [
                {
                    name: "data-hello",
                    value: "hello"
                },
                {
                    name: "data-world",
                    value: "world"
                }
            ]
        },
        lastNameField: {
            for: "lastName",
            labelText: "Last Name",
            name: "lastName",
            attr: [
                {
                    name: "placeholder",
                    value: "Smith"
                },
                {
                    name: "data-someAttr",
                    value: "someAttr"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

**Rendered markup**

```
<div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text" data-hello="hello" data-world="world">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Smith" value="Smith">
</div>
```

After getting it all together, the solution feels *odd* to me.  Perhaps I'm just not using the tool right and/or need to establish a better understanding of tempting engines and their intended purpose, but the solution above enabled me to achieve the end result I was looking for which was to be able to define a reusable collection of html elements, in a partial/template/etc, that can have varying attributes/attribute values.

Feedback is certainly appreciated.  If there is a better way of implementing, please let me know.

Related/relevant links:

- [Partial Variables in Mustache](https://coderwall.com/p/niectg/partial-variables-in-mustache)